# onDeviceReady never gets called in Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am just trying to run a simple page within the inappbrowser plugin. I am running Cordova 5.0, and the plugin is version 1.0. I run the app with the splashscreen plugin and it seems to work fin. The default splashscreen runs when the app start but the in app browser plugin does not seem to work. Here is my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
//
function onLoad() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
alert("dfs");

var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });

}
</script>


</head> 


    <body onload="onLoad()">
    </body>
</html>
```

The cordova.js file is properly linked I assume since that is the correct path. I have also uninstalled and installed the plugin back, created a new project and none of them seem to solve my problem. I am testing it on my Android 5.0 smartphone and Android 4.1 emulator. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just include corodova.js as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

And use ripple emulator [which is a google plugin] and you will see onDeviceReady() is fired. Acutually this works well for me. Please try it

Comment: I did add the cordova.js file if you look at my code. I just specified the path since I don't have the file in the same folder as my index.html in the www folder.

Comment: May I Know where do you get that corodova.js file from ?

Comment: <main-dir>/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js

Comment: Ya. I think so. But I have no idea. I have developed an android app [which you can get it from www.altharaiammankovil.org ] for which I used the steps above. I mean the ripple emulator

Comment: When you included your cordova.js file, where was it located when you maid your app?

Comment: I dont have such a file. It will show a 404 error when i use it local in my browser but when i use build.phonegap.com and build the app, the corodova.js file will be automatically included by phone gap